# Android Create Icon Wizard: Where is my high res 512 x 512 image?

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, adt

So I used the great "Create Asset Set" Wizard in the ADT to design my icon. Now I need a high res (512 x 512 pixels) version of the icon for the store.

Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

It is copied to the root folder of your project in the workspace.

It is called

your_icon_name-web.png